# numpy machine precision for dot product?

Tags: python, numpy

How do I deal with the floats precision in numpy? For example in the following `a==0` returns False, even though up to machine precision it's 0:

```
a = -2.22044605e-16
```

This is particularly an issue because I am taking dot products of vectors and it seems like the results is affected, i.e. a is treated as a 'negative' number.

```
np.finfo(float).eps
```

returns -2.22044605e-16

Here is an example:

```
a = np.array([[-2.22044605e-16,-2.22044605e-16]])

b = np.array([[5,5]])

np.dot(a,b)
array([[ -2.22044605e-15]])

a = np.array([[-2.22044605e-16,2.22044605e-16]])
np.dot(a,b.T)
array([[ 0.]])
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by dealing with floats precision?

Comment: `-2.22044605e-16` isn't zero up to machine precision (and it _is_ a negative number)... I'm not sure what you mean...

Comment: You're misinterpreting the `resolution` attribute. It's `10**-precision`, where `precision` is the approximate number of decimal digits of precision available for the floating-point type you're inspecting. Thus, `resolution` is a (rather bad) approximation of the smallest number you can add to `1.0` without just getting `1.0` back. See the [`finfo` docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.finfo.html).

Comment: actually np.finfo(float).eps returns -2.22044605e-16. How should I interpret that?

Comment: a dot product can be a negative number when angles are **obtuse**

Comment: I am aware of this, that's not the point @Paul

Comment: In the first dot product the angle is about 180 degrees, and the dot product should be approximately negative the product of the lengths, which it is.  In the second dot product the angle is 90 degrees, and the dot product is zero.  Sounds good so far.  So what's wrong?

Comment: [5,5] .dot. [-x,x] = -5x + 5x = 0, doesn't matter what x is, i.e. x could be 2.22044605e-16 or anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Try [`numpy.allclose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html).

From the link:

`numpy.allclose(a, b, rtol=1e-05, atol=1e-08)`

> Returns True if two arrays are element-wise equal within a tolerance.
>
> The tolerance values are positive, typically very small numbers. The
>   relative difference (rtol * abs(b)) and the absolute difference atol
>   are added together to compare against the absolute difference between
>   a and b.
>
> If either array contains one or more NaNs, False is returned. Infs are
>   treated as equal if they are in the same place and of the same sign in
>   both arrays.

---

> If the following equation is element-wise True, then allclose returns `True`:
>
> ```
>     absolute(a - b) <= (atol + rtol * absolute(b))
> ```

**Example**:

```
>>> np.allclose([1e10,1e-7], [1.00001e10,1e-8])
False
>>> np.allclose([1e10,1e-8], [1.00001e10,1e-9])
True
>>> np.allclose([1e10,1e-8], [1.0001e10,1e-9])
False
>>> np.allclose([1.0, np.nan], [1.0, np.nan])
False
```

**So:**

Instead of doing:

```
>>> 0 == -2.22044605e-16
False
```

do:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.allclose([0], [-2.22044605e-16])
True
```

Comment: 0 == -2.22044605e-16 is not actually what i am doing, this is just an example. The point is that if I have two arrays, a and b, with a bunch of -2.22044605e-16 in them, and I take their dot product, the results are different (see the addition in the question)

Comment: This is a good answer for a precision issue. Actually, since his vector values are initialized to O(1e-16) I don't think precision is the issue here.

Answer (score 2):

Although `a` may equal [machine epsilon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) that does not make it a zero! In fact `2.22044605e-16` is much larger than the smallest represent-able value for float64, which is:

```
np.finfo(float).tiny  # = 2.2250738585072014e-308
```

I guess what you're seeing here is the [propagation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ErrorPropagation.html) of a [round-off error](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RoundoffError.html). In your second example you just got lucky that the round-off errors cancel out.